# orderedlinkedlist JAVA counting words in .txt file no duplicate words plus counter>

Tags: java, list, foreach, count, cpu-word

Okay this program is supposed to count the number of times each word shows up in a .txt file I'm on the right track because this program shows every word in the file in a text area but I need it to not repeat words and increment a counter instead. Am I on the right track under the for each word:words statement? It's in an ordered linked list so the words are in order alphabetically...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Oct29 extends JPanel
{
  private OrderedList<String> words;
  private String filename;
  private int width = 800;
  private int height = 600;
  private TextArea textarea;

  public Oct29()
  {
    Scanner scan;
    textarea = new TextArea("",0,0,TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
    textarea.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,24));
    textarea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    add(textarea);
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("../Text");
    int returnvalue = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if(returnvalue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
      try
      {
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        filename = file.getName();
        System.err.println(filename);
        scan = new Scanner(file);
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        System.err.println("IO EXCEPTION");
        return;
      }       
    }
    else
    {
      return;
    }
    words = new OrderedLinkedList<String>();
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
      String token = scan.next().toLowerCase();
      token = token.replace(",","").replace(".","");
      words.add(token);
    }
    scan.close();
    textarea.append("    "+filename+" has wordcount: "+words.size()+
      "\n-------------------------\n\n");

     for(String word : words)
     {     
        textarea.append(word+"\n");  // instead of displaying each word I need it to read when the word changes and then list a count of that word...
     }
  }

  public static void main(String[] arg)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Oct 29");
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Oct29());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about this

1) As you are reading them in keep a counter for each word and then when you output this you can output the counter

2) As you are outputting keep a counter and when the word changes then you output the counter and the word and then set the counter back to zero.

You can start by in your for loop using String.equals.
Then if this is true, increment. If its false then do whatever you need (assign the value somewhere or just output it) and then set the counter to 0.

Comment: I'm currently attempting option 2 trying to figure out how to count for the word and when it changes reset the counter...

Comment: So you will need 1) an if statement , 2) a counter variable, 3) String.equals() ---> as in your variable word.equals("String you are testing it against")

Comment: String current= null;
  
          for(String word : words)
          {
            int count = 0;
            if ( current != null && !(current.equals(word)))
              count++;
             textarea.append(word+" " + count + "\n");
          }

Comment: Where are you assigning current? Also you probably want to be testing for equality? You wont the count of each word right?

Comment: Yes I do. I'm putting current in my for each loop?

Comment: If you set current to null outside the loop and then test if its not null inside the if statement then the first time round you are going to get an issue.

Comment: for(String word : words)
     {
       String current = word;
       int count = 0;
       if ( current != null && !(current.equals(word)))
         count++;
        textarea.append(current+" " + count + "\n");
       count = 0;
     }

Comment: Sorry about the bad formatting, not sure how to comment code yet

Comment: personally i would of used a for loop to worry about less corner cases. The code below is probably a good starting point for this using the for each however I wont gurantee its correct as you need to think about the what happens on the last word and the first word which is contained in words.

Comment: //personally i would of used a for loop and used the first word as previous to risk less corner     
    //cases however this should work fine  
    String previous = "";
    int counter = 0;
    for(String word : words)
     {     
        if(word.equals(previous)){
          counter = counter + 1;
        else{
         textarea.append(word);  
         textarea.append(counter + "\n"); //you may need to change the int into a string first here
         counter = 1;//because when we get here we have seen the new word once
         previous = word;
        }

Comment: Okay this works:String current = "";
    int count = 0; for(String word : words)
     {
       if(current.equals(word))
       {
         count++;
       }
       else
       {
       textarea.append(current+": " + count +"\n");
       current = word;
       count = 1;
       }
     }

Comment: my only problem is that the first output in my list is ":0"  why is that?

Comment: because current starts off as the empty string to begin with. Thats why at the beginning it is ":0". (one of the corner cases). Your best bet is to set current as the first word in words (once again recheck your code after making this change as you may need to change count).